# 2 Jquery конфликтуют между собой

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, библиотеки

Привет всем.  Я ничего не понимаю в js и jquery поэтому обращаюсь к вам, знатоки)

**Есть скрипт для анимации:**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
//animate1
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post4').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated shake',
    offset: 100
  });
});
//animate2
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post3').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInDown',
    offset: 10
  });
});
//animate3
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post2').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInRightBig',
    offset: 10
  });
});
//animate4
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInUp',
    offset: 100
  });
});
});
```

**И есть библиотека jquery**

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

При подключении обоих скриптов, анимашка не работает, отключаю 1.9.1 тогда анимашка работает, но без 1.9.1 не работает форма обратной связи как подобает. Подскажите как исправить, искренне буду благодарен вам.

Comment: А какая версия работает без 1.9.1 нашли?

Comment: Какая версия чего именно, простите?

Comment: Какая версия jQuery, разумеется.

Comment: Нет, нет, не нашел, к сожалению